# Find computers that are not members of a specific GG group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I use a script to export users that are not in specific GG groups in active directory but I want to do the same with computers.

This is the example that works with users:

```
$groups = 'GG_LCS_UsersType4', 'GG_LCS_UsersType3', 'GG_LCS_UsersType2', 'GG_LCS_SpecialUsers'
$whereFilter = $groups | Foreach-Object { 
    $g = (Get-ADGroup -server $domain $_).DistinguishedName
    "{0} '{1}'" -f '$_.memberOf -notcontains',$g 
}
$whereFilter = [scriptblock]::Create($whereFilter -join " -and ")
$users = (Get-ADUser -server $Domain -filter {objectclass -eq "user"} -properties memberof).where($whereFilter)
$users | Select-Object SamAccountName,Enabled |
    Export-Csv "${Domain}_Users_withoutGG.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

And I tried this in order to do the same with computers, but this doesn't work:

```
$groups = 'GG_LCS_ComputersType2', 'GG_LCS_ComputersType3', 'GG_LCS_ComputersType4'
$whereFilter = $groups | Foreach-Object { 
    $g = (Get-ADGroup -server $domain $_).DistinguishedName
    "{0} '{1}'" -f '$_.memberOf -notcontains',$g 
}
$whereFilter = [scriptblock]::Create($whereFilter -join " -and ")
$users = (Get-ADComputer -server $Domain -filter {objectclass -eq "computer"} -properties memberof).where($whereFilter)
$users | Select-Object SamAccountName,Enabled |
    Export-Csv "${Domain}_Computers_withoutGG.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Depends. What doesn't work the way you expected (i.e. what result did you expect, and what result did you actually get)?

Comment: I tried this on my PC and it works as expected based on my interpretation. The only thing I would change is selecting SamAccountName at the end. SamAccountName for a computer object would include a $. For computers, I would switch to `Select-Object Name,Enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the -SearchBase

```
$AD = Get-ADComputer  -Filter *  -Properties $properties -SearchBase "DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com" -Server $server
$AD | Select-Object * | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $filePath -Encoding UTF8
```